# How do I calculate the width and height of UIButton given the text and font?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27263779/179736), I can use `intrinsicContentSize` to automatically calculate the width/height.  That's what I did, but the result is `0, 0`

```
class AutoSizeUIButton: UIButton{
    override func intrinsicContentSize() -> CGSize {
        return CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width, self.titleLabel!.frame.size.height)
    }
}


networkButton.setTitle("something-here", forState: .Normal)
networkButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 20.0)!
let networkSize = networkButton.intrinsicContentSize()
print("button size", networkSize.width, networkSize.height)  //prints 0.0, 0.0
```

Am I doing something wrong? Note: I don't want to use constraints. I just want to print the width/height.

Comment: Try this code UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:30];
NSDictionary *userAttributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: font,
                                 NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor blackColor]};
NSString *text = @"hello";
...
const CGSize textSize = [text sizeWithAttributes: userAttributes];

Answer (score 5):

Try networkButton.sizeThatFits.

```
let networkSize = networkButton.sizeThatFits(CGSizeZero)
print("button size", networkSize.width, networkSize.height)
```

(The parameter passed to sizeThatFits is often ignored and poorly documented. I'm not sure if CGSizeZero works everywhere - maybe you should pass an arbitrarily large size)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
networkButton.sizeToFit()
```

Now the size of Network Button fits it's text