# How to center view with dynamic height using auto layout

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, autolayout, constraints

I'm trying to programmatically create a view that is centered inside a designated superview. I can almost achieve this behavior, however the centered view does not respect the dynamic height of its content. Here is the function I created to make it happen:

```
static func overlayWithButton(onView view: UIView, buttonText: String, theme: Theme = .dark, action: Action? = nil) -> UIView {
    // create overlay
    let overlay = UIView()
    overlay.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    let leftInset: CGFloat = 20
    let rightInset: CGFloat = 20

    // Style overlay
    overlay.backgroundColor = theme == .dark ? UIColor.black : UIColor.white
    overlay.alpha = 0.75
    overlay.cornerRadius = 10

    // create button
    let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    // Style Button
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    button.setTitle(buttonText, for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(theme == .dark ? lightBlueButtonText : UIColor.black, for: .normal)
    button.titleLabel?.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
    button.titleLabel?.textAlignment = .center
    button.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
    button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)
    button.isEnabled = true

    // add button action
    if let action = action {
        button.add(for: .touchUpInside, action)
    }

    // add constraints
    overlay.addSubview(button)
    button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: overlay.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    button.leftAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: overlay.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    button.rightAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: overlay.rightAnchor).isActive = true

    button.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: overlay.topAnchor).isActive = true
    button.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: overlay.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

    view.addSubview(overlay)
    overlay.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: leftInset).isActive = true
    overlay.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: -rightInset).isActive = true
    overlay.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

    return overlay
}
```

This works with short button titles:
[image: it works!]
However, with longer title, the button content is clipped:
[image]
Using reveal I can see that the title / button label is responding as intended.
[image: it does not work]
I've been at this for quite a while now, and I can't get the centered overlay to expand its height to match the intrinsic content size of its contents. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you set the height anchor for the overlay equal to the height anchor for the button?

Comment: I get the same result if I do that instead of the top/bottom anchors, and the same result if I do that in addition to the top/bottom anchors.

Comment: I suspect that this is something to do with the translatesAutoResizingMaskIntoContraints getting rid of the intrinsic content size of the UIButton, but I need to set that to true, otherwise all the other constraints  applied to the button don't work.

Comment: Are you calling `setNeedsLayout` and `layoutIfNeeded` ?

Comment: Where should I be making those calls?

Comment: Interestingly enough, when I change the button to a normal label, things work the way I expect. This means it has something to do with the fact that it is a UIButton that contains a UILabel (button.titleLabel) that is throwing everything off.

Comment: Hi ! Have you checked my Answer ?

Comment: @BadalShah Yes, and thank you for putting so much thought into the response! Unfortunately I require a programmatic solution (as specified in my question). Also, and perhaps was less clear about this, but I need to content centered in the view to be a button allowed to overflow multiple lines of text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After extensive digging, it turns out the problem is due to a funky interaction between a UIButton and its label. See [this stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27259333/uibutton-that-resizes-to-fit-its-titlelabel) for more details on that specific issue. While none of the top-voted solutions succeeded in helping me fix the issue, there was [a solution further down](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45618411/3600114) that did help. The solution lies in creating a UIButton subclass that overrides intrinsicContentSize and layoutSubviews. Code for such a subclass here:

```
class LongTitleButton: UIButton {

    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        return self.titleLabel?.intrinsicContentSize ?? super.intrinsicContentSize
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        if let titleLabel = titleLabel {
            titleLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = titleLabel.frame.size.width
        }
    }

}
```

Alternatively, since this issue seems to be specific to UIButton, an equally effective alternative solution would be to simply use a UILabel instead of a UIButton, placing a UIGestureRecognizer on the label instead.

Answer (score 0):

I got your Problem , You Don't need to take All programatically and set Size According to your Text.

### Here i have Attached Step by Step Guid , Please Follow this .

**Step 1 :-** Take one View (We call it PopupView) and One Label as Subview    in PopupView.

[image]

**Step 2 :-** Set Initial Constrain to PopupView and UILabel as Describe below.

```
PopupView = LeadingConstrain(20) and TrialingConstrain(20) (From its Superview = mainview)
  UILabel = LeadingConstrain(10) and TrialingConstrain(10) (From its Superview =popupView)
```

[image]

**Step 3 :-**  **Most tricky** - **Press RighClick of Mouse** and Drag PopUpview to UILabel.Now You need to **Press Shift** key and **Click on Topspace to Container and Bottom Space to Container**..

```
 PopupView Topspace to UILabel Top Space
 popupview BottomSpace to UILabel Bottom Space
 set UIlabe number of Line = 0 
 and LineBreak = WordwrapMode
```

[image]

**Step 4 :-** Now Set Constrain to PopupView and Update Frames.

```
Set Center Horizontally in Container
Set Center Vertically in Container
```

[image]

**Step 5 :-** in ThNe Last Step, Click on PopupView . select Top Constrain of view and Set Aprroproate Distance of UILabel to View from top and Follow same for Bottom.

[image]

**Step 6 :-** Now see Preview for Short label on Multiple Devices.

[image]

**Step 7 :-** Now Add long Line text in UILabel , Run in Simulator and Check for Portrait and LandScape both Mode.

[image]

I hope now your issue will be clear. If you need any help , feel free to ask in Comment.

Here i have Also Attached Demo for Your Reference , [UILabel with Center Dynamic Height](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=56134972673352858926)