# Dynamic size of button in stack view depending on text length

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I have button with text in stack view, and on button init this text is short, but when I click on this button text is changing for longer text, but height of this button is not good.

I set this properties on button, but still not working

```
button.titleLabel?.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
button.titleLabel?.textAlignment = .left
button.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
```

How can I get dynamic size of button depending on text length?

Comment: Please, post screenshots of the button and the stack view constraints on the storyboard. Also, I'm not sure, but you probably need to call `view.setNeedsLayout()` when you change the button text.

Comment: `addSubview(stackView)
stackView.addArrangedSubview(titleButton)
stackView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.bottom.leading.trailing.equalToSuperview()
        }`

I don't use storyboards, I don't set any constraints for button. `view.setNeedsLayout` not working

Comment: You using some UI custom library?

Comment: No, I don't use any UI Custom library, only SnapKit.

Comment: It *is* custom. Try to connect the developers (post issue on GitHub) and tell about your problem.

Comment: This is resolution of this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27259333/uibutton-that-resizes-to-fit-its-titlelabel